# C#-Winforms-How to use instance objects in different subforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a "MainForm" and a "GraphicsForm". Clicking "New" on the main form, a "GraphicsForm" will be created.

The problem is that when I create multiple "GraphicsForm", and when I want to save the content of one of the "GraphicsForm", I need to clicking "Save" on the "MainForm" and the program will save the content of the active "GraphicsForm" to a file, I don't know how to pass the content of this "GraphicsForm" to "MainForm" for storage.

MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ToolStripMenuItem _winMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    private GraphicsForm _graphicsForm;
    private int _counter = 1;

    private void New_Click(objec sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _winMenuItem.Name = "Win";
        _winMenuItem.Text = "Windows";
        int item = MainMenuStrip.Items.IndexOf(_winMenuItem);
        if (item == -1)
        {
            MainMenuStrip.Items.Add(_winMenuItem);
            MainMenuStrip.MdiWindowListItem = _winMenuItem;
        }

        _graphicsForm = new GraphicsForm();
        _graphicsForm.Name = string.Concat("Win_", _counter.ToString());
        _graphicsForm.Text = _graphicsForm.Name;
        _graphicsForm.MdiParent = this;
        _graphicsForm.Show();
        _graphicsForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        _counter++;
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... // Problem here
    }

    private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... // Problem here
    }
}
```

GraphicsForm.cs

```
public partial class GraphicsForm : Form
{
    //StorageDoc is a class to manage all the graphics drawn by the user in the form.

    private StorageDoc _storageDoc = new StotageDoc();

    public GraphicsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Canvas_MouseDown()
    {
    }
    
    private Canvas_Paint()
    {
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: When do you want to save the contents? What triggers that? Why does the MainForm need to know anything about storage? (Ideally, the UI classes should only know about UI concerns - "how to save data" can be in a different class...)

Comment: Why can't the `GraphicsForm` do its own storage?

Comment: @jmcilhinney because the "Save" button in "MainForm".

Comment: Is there a save method in MainForm so that I just need to pass a GraphicsForm instance to it? How do you know which GraphicsForm to save when the save button is pressed?

Comment: @shingo Yes, there is a save method in MainForm, But i dont know how to pass the instance to MainForm. And I dont know how to get which GraphicsForm is active when i created mutiple GraphicsForm.

Comment: @JonSkeet When I Click "Save" button in "MainForm" to save the contents.

Comment: @K.K You should mention the kind of the Graphics contents. Depending on this, you can get better suggestions. Is it a picture, chart, shapes?

Comment: @jtxkopt absolutely, the contents of GraphicsForm are some shapes. The data for these graphics are saved to a list.

Comment: Is this a MDI form? If not you cannot get the active GraphicsForm because MainForm must be active when the save button can be pressed. To get the last actived GraphicsForm could be a choice.

Comment: @shingo Yes they are MDI forms. The "GraphicsForm" is MDI child of "MainForm".

Comment: So if you've opened multiple forms, how do you *expect* it to know which form you want to save the data from? (You should edit your question to be much, much clearer.) Note that by the time you click on the Save button in MainForm, that would surely be the active window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `MainForm` is a MDI form, it is easy to use [ActiveMdiChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ActiveMdiChild) to get the active child form.

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    public void OnSaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ActiveMdiChild is GraphicsForm g)
            Save(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error is that "The first operand of an 'is' or 'as' operator may not be a lambda expression, anonymous method, or method group."

Comment: `ActiveMdiChild` is a property, it's not that you listed. Can you show your code?

Comment: Did you write Activ**ate**MdiChild?

Comment: I edited my question. I added my code. Please check it out.

Comment: I got it with ActiveMdiChild.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been answered before but basically, you pass in an instance of the 'data storage' to the new form.

```
interface ISaveForm
{
    void Save();
}

class MainForm
{
    private DataStorage _dataStorage;
    private ICollection<ISaveForm> _forms = new List<ISaveForm>();

    public void OnNew()
    {
        var subForm = new GraphicsForm(_dataStorage);
        subForm.Show();
        _forms.Add(subForm);
    }
    public void OnSave()
    {
       foreach(var form in _forms)
       {
         form.Save();
       }
    }
}
class GraphicsForm : Form,ISaveForm
{
    private DataStorage _dataStorage;

    public GraphicsForm(DataStorage dataStorage)
    {
        _dataStorage = dataStorage;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code of yours doesn't seem to solve my problem, I have shown my code. Take a look at it.

Comment: I've looked at your updated code.   My suggestion will solve your problem.

Comment: None of the functions seem to be implemented to get the active graphicsForm. That is also one of my questions.